# Chess Connect Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, chess, grid-deduction

I made up a new logic puzzle based on the games [Numberlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numberlink) and Chess, and thought it ended up rather interesting. The solution, as usual, is unique.

**The starting and ending positions of 7 chess pieces are shown on the board. Find the trajectories of the pieces, if you know that they do not overlap and completely cover the board.**

[image]

*Remark: Every two consecutive squares in the Queen's trajectory are either diagonally or horizontally/vertically adjacent. Every two consecutive squares in the Rooks' trajectories are horizontally/vertically adjacent. Every two consecutive squares in the Bishops' trajectories are diagonally adjacent. Every two consecutive squares in the Knights' trajectories are 2 horizontal and 1 vertical cells apart, or 2 vertical and 1 horizontal cells apart.*

Comment: @Alconja, the knight trajectories are not continuous.

Comment: Was trying to make it a bit clearer for people who hadn't played the game, but you're right, perhaps I've introduced potential confusion... Perhaps you can think of better wording? (Nice puzzle btw)

Comment: @Alconja, thanks. Let's revert it back to the original wording and I will think tomorrow for a better one? I have added a detailed description in the remark, but indeed it will be good to come up with a succinct and precise formulation.

Comment: Nice idea to connect these two :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe this works (under the assumption that paths consist only of the squares visited by each piece, not by the lines created, allowing diagonal lines to "cross" each other, and the knights' obvious need to "jump"):

> [image: solution]

Comment: Couldn't the black knight take a1, or the black rook g1 and h1, or the queen g3 and g4? Or does the question also intend to impose the additional unstated restriction that the piece trajectories cannot branch off?

Comment: @noedne - I don't follow... you mean as in capture the pieces? I was assuming (perhaps incorrectly), that the primary ruleset was numberlink, but with chess based movement (i.e. no piece will take anything, they'll all just avoid each other)

Comment: In Numberlink you're only supposed to connect numbers together and no more (in particular you can't go further in a line), so I suspect the same applies here

Comment: @Alconja Sorry, by "take," I meant travel through that square.

Comment: @Alconja's interpretation and solution are correct. I will accept this tomorrow:)

Comment: @noedne - ahh, then I think (again based my interpretation, though it seems phenomist agrees), we're just trying to find *a* path for each pair of pieces that satisfies the numberlink rules (i.e. all squares covered and no paths "crossing"), not all possible paths.

Comment: @Alconja Then the solution would not be unique.

Comment: @noedne - it *becomes* unique if you continue to solve. E.g. the black rook going via G1/H1 is *allowed* from a movement perspective, but if you tried that, then it would end up blocking the queen's path (which *may* be ok, except that trying to move the queen's path would ultimately block another path, etc), which rules that path segment out as part of the solution.

Comment: @Alconja In that scenario, the queen could travel via Qg1-f1 instead of Qh1-f1.

Comment: @noene - but the pieces as shown on the board are the terminal points of their paths... and their movement can't cross another path, *including* their own. So if the queen went G1-F1, and the rook went to H1, it would be stuck, as it can't return to H2 (to subsequently go further north) by the numberlink rules.

Comment: @Alconja Ah, I see that I was not familiar with the rules of Numberlink. Maybe the rule about the pieces not retracing their paths should be clarified in the question?

Comment: I know I'm a bit late here but I can't help pointing out that the remark does exactly that

Comment: @Wen1now - once you actually try to solve it, the correct interpretation becomes necessarily apparent. But the remark only clarifies chess piece movement, it says nothing of numberlink rules, retracing steps, valid paths from connective lines vs paths from visited squares, etc...

Comment: I did consider the other interpretation but ruled it out almost immediately as too unrestricted.. bu yeah, the numberlink rules should've been stated explicitly instead of linked